# Javascript "this" overridden by event listener

Tags: javascript, oop, events

I am probably doing something wrong but I found some interesting behavior when trying to apply some object oriented programming to Javascript.  Consider the following

```
function Bug(element) {
    this.focusedCell = null;
    element.addEventListener('click', this.onClick, true);
};

Bug.prototype.onClick = function(event){
    console.log("this is: ");
    console.log(this);
};
```

When I call the method from the console, I see the correct instance of "this" but when I click the element in the document I see the document element in lieu of the instance.  So... chances are it's probably not a good idea to use event listeners with instance methods, at least the way I'm doing it.

So the question is:

- Is it possible to have an event listener like this that calls an instance method of a javascript object, while preserving the instance in the call?
- Is there a better pattern for doing this?

Edit:
I haven't tried this in anything but Chrome. But I would imagine that the behavior is the same.

Comment: The function creates a new scope.

Comment: Thanks, sorry didn't know it was a duplicate search didn't show up with anything.

Comment: @FelixKling Wow sweet you found an perfect dup..

Comment: There are actually tons of duplicates, but they probably have weird titles.

Comment: I [googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=event+listener+overrides+this&aq=f&oq=event+listen&aqs=chrome.0.59j57j0j60l2j0.1574j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) it too but nada. I searched for "overriding this" on SO but didn't find it.  I didn't know that it was explicitly related to the event listener that was overriding, it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a better pattern, and doesn't require much change. I'll show the code first.

```
function Bug(element) {
    this.focusedCell = null;
    // --------------------------------v----pass the object, not a function
    element.addEventListener('click', this, true);
};

// Implement the `EventListener` interface
Bug.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
    if (event.type === "click")
        this.onClick(event);
}

Bug.prototype.onClick = function(event) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this));         // '{"focusedCell":null}'
    console.log(event.currentTarget.nodeName); // "DIV"
};
```

By adding the `handleEvent` method, we make `Bug` implement the `EventListener` interface. This allows us to pass the new `Bug` object as the second argument to `addEventListener()` instead of a function.

Now when the `"click"` event happens, the `.handleEvent()` method will be invoked, and the value of `this` in that method will be the `Bug` object that was bound.

---

Since `this` is a reference to the `Bug` instance, it obviously won't be a reference to the element anymore. But it's not necessary, since the element is available via `event.currentTarget`.

Of course, you could add the element directly to your `Bug` object in the constructor if desired.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/CnZTa/

---

Comment: This is very elegant, but will also require some sort of polyfill for IE8 and earlier.

Comment: @bfavaretto: True, but OP is using `addEventListener` already in the question. Don't know if a shim is needed or already being used.

Comment: I like simplicity behind this, my actual class has a lot more event handling and this looks to be the nicest fit.  But as bfavaretto pointed out, I will have to look at older browser support.

Comment: Oh the irony... my own answer is using `addEventListener` too! Just not `handleEvent`.

Comment: @lukecampbell: Yeah, most browsers support `.addEventListener()`, but as bfavaretto pointed out, IE8 and lower will need a shim.

Comment: @bfavaretto: ...not to mention `Function.prototype.bind()`. ;-) Though you did mention the need for a polyfill. If OP doesn't support IE8, then no need for either shim!

Comment: Thanks all, I tried both `bind` and this one out and they both work, at least on Chrome ;)

Comment: @lukecampbell: If you have lots of other event types, consider naming your methods after the events. Then your `handleEvent()` method can simply do `return this[event.type] && this[event.type](event);`

Comment: I wish I could upvote that more than once squint.

Comment: [The code here](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/handleevent) can be used to provide compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: +1... that's great! I've been developing JavaScript applications for a while now and I did not even know this feature existed! So much more efficient than `bind` in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: @plalx: Yeah, I think it's the best kept secret in JavaScript. Provides such a nice coupling between JS data/classes and DOM elements.

Comment: @squint hehe, I guess there will be much more to learn once Harmony kicks-in ;)

Comment: I guess someone doesn't like *(or more likely understand)* this solution? If you're not familiar with this technique, by all means, ask about it. I'd be happy to explain more.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Function.prototype.bind` to create a listener bound to whatever *this* value you want:

```
function Bug(element) {
    this.focusedCell = null;
    element.addEventListener('click', this.onClick.bind(this), true);
};
```

Older (non-ES5) browsers will need a polyfill such as the one from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior in JavaScript. You can preserve your expected `this` by passing an function the the listener:

```
function Bug(element) {
    var self = this; // Store a reference to this
    this.focusedCell = null;
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // in here this refers to element
        self.onClick(event);
    }, true);
};

Bug.prototype.onClick = function(event){
    console.log("this is: "); 
    console.log(this); // In here this refers the an instance of Bug.
};
```

Comment: The code is right, but the explanation is not very clear. `"by passing a function to the listener"`... this is what the OP does already. The difference is that the function is defined inline in your case, so it creates a closure over the parent function's scope which allows to access the `self` variable from the handler function.